# Let $T: Y \rightarrow X$ be a isometry, where $X$ is Banach and reflexive. Construct a completion $(Z,i)$, where $Z$ is banach and $i(Y)$ is dense

Tags: functional-analysis

i am kind of new to these second duals and reflexives spaces and saw this question which i don't really understand. Can you help me a bit or hint me in the right direction?

Let $T: Y \rightarrow X$ be a isometry, where $X$ is Banach and reflexive. Construct a completion $(Z,i)$, where  $Z$ is banach and $i(Y)$ is dense in $Z$ Prove that this completion is a reflexive space.

If i want to make a completion of $Y$ using $T$, i think my completion looks like this:

$(X'',J_XT)$

Now how do we see this density of $J_X(T)$ in $Z$? I know $i(Y)$ is isometrically isomorphic to a dense subset of $Z$, but this dense subset does not need to be $Z$ right?

and for the reflexivity: We know $X$ is reflexive and banach, so $X'$ is reflexive, but note that X' is banach too, so $X''$ must be reflexive!

Comment: ??? Surely the completion they want is just the closure of $T(Y)$ in $X$...

Comment: how do you mean, like taking the completion (X,T)? But how do you see if $T(Y)$ is dense in $X$, does that follow from the fact that T is an isometry?

Comment: No, I mean exactly what I said! $T(Y)$ is a subset of $X$. Say its closure in $X$ is $Z$. Define $i:Y\to Z$ by $iy=Ty$. Then $Z$ is complete, being a closed subset of a complete space, $i(Y)$ is dense in $Z$ (which is what's required, not dense in $X$!) by construction, and $i$ is an isometry.

Comment: wow it is much simpler than i thought, thanks :D